# Booking Function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I try to make a booking system in vb.net and are stuck with a problem. I want to populate a combobox with availible items from my database and not the items that already are booked.

The variables from my database is Date_start and Date_end and store information on when an item is booked.

The new order has Order_start and Order_end as variables.

I basically want to check if the periode between Date_start and Date_end is the same as between Order_start and Order_end.

I think it has to be somthing like this, but I dont get it to work:

```
If Date_start >= Order_start And Date_end <= Order_end Then 
    'Add to combobox
End If
```

Can somebody help me to think logical?

Thanks:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ranges themselves are valid (e.g., Order_end isn't before Order_start) and you're just checking to make sure the two date ranges don't overlap, you can use

```
If Date_start > Order_end OrElse Order_start > Date_end Then
```

In English, it just makes sure either range has ended before the other starts.